# Error requests are not logged in the server for load test in Jmeter with 1000 users

Tags: server, jmeter, error-logging

I have done jmeter load testing for APIs and I have got error percentages for above 1000 users, when the developer is checking if the jmter server hits the api, he is complaining that,only success requests are logged and error hits are not logged.Please let me know the answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please share the code snippets you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

try saving these properties in jmeter.properties or user.properties file and enable them .by default they are false  hope this helps.

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true

jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true

jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=true
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion,but i want to know, why jmeter shows error percentage for the requests which crosses 21000 ms of response time and iam getting a "java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect" error.let me know about this ?

Comment: One more thing is ,my developer complains that he is getting only success logs in the server.and he cant get the error logs,is there any server side configuration?let me know.

Comment: You are saying it is  java.net.ConnectException " means you machine could not able to establish a connection to server .. check the internet connectivity ..  or another reason might , band width was not sufficient to send that many requests . I see here this is a client problem . for server problems Ask developer to enable server logs .. example in case we have settings INFO,DEBUG,ERROR ,TRACE32 ask developer to enable fine grain logging. Click up if it is useful